# parameter passing in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-2.7

```
def topMatches(prefs,person,n=5,similarity=sim_pearson):
  scores=[(similarity(prefs,person,other),other)
                  for other in prefs if other!=person]  
  scores.sort()
  scores.reverse()
  return scores[0:n]
```

I'm just calling another function within topmatches function,
My doubt is how the **other** works i have not defined it elsewhere
Also I have not passed it to the function topmatches,
***Can anyone explain me how this works?***

Comment: Are you reading <Programming Collective Intelligence>?

Comment: `other` is a temporary index variable

Comment: yes i have just started of with it ,finding it very useful than other books on ML!@Satoru.Logic

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: can u suggest better resources like <PCI> book on ML, i found this book after going through many vague books on machine learning!

Comment: @iamsiva11 The theory behind machine learning and implementation details like performance is not discussed in this book. After all it's  more like a one-algorithm-a-chapter book. I guess you'll need to read some `harder` book on the subject, which I myself is searching for ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unroll your `scores=[(similarity(prefs,person,other),other) for other in prefs if other!=person]` to something like this to see what is happening.

```
scores = []
for other in prefs:
    if other != person:
        scores.append((similarity(prefs, person, other))
```

So what happens is this:

1. You create an empty list called scores
2. You iterate through prefs, and placing the value of that element into a variable `other` thereby instantiating it
3. You check to make sure `other` doesn't equal `person`
4. And if not, you call your similarity function and append the results into `scores`

The construct you have posted is called a list comprehension which can be a nice, neat, fast way of writing what can be a series of normal loops etc.

EDIT (courtesy of moooeeeep):

[PEP202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) on List Comprehensions, and the actual [documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions).

Comment: +1 - just to add two links for further reading: [PEP202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), [the docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thanks for the links, added them to the post. :)

Answer (score 4):

`other` is a the list element for each `record` in `prefs`.

Comment: but when i call this function i just do
recom.topMatches(recom.critics,'Test',n=5),so i pass person here,where does other come from?.

Comment: in python you don't have to declare variables before you use them; `other` is created local to the list comprehension which is assigned the name `scores`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no programming experience -

topMatches is your function.

other is a temporary variable. This variable is defined INSIDE the topMatches function. In python, you do not explicitly need to "declare" a variable to create it.

For example,

in c,

```
void topMatches( . , . , . )
{
  int other;

.
.
.
}
```

You would have had something like this, where other was defined to be a variable.

but in python, if I simply do,

```
for other in prefs:
<something something>
```

The python compiler understands on its own that you want to create a temporary variable with the name of "other" that is iterating over your loop. (in the example you gave).

It is equivalent to saying,

```
for (int i;i<n;i++)
. 
.
```

where i is a variable iterator for your loop. (In C).

Similarly, in Python, "other" is variable iterator for the loop in this example. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: And that was a wrong assumption,I got it anyways.thanks for ur time!